# Apllication form on MSWord2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm filling in an application form using MSWord2007...the problem is, that when you fill in the spaces left for my details etc, it pushes all the other information out of line and the font size keeps changing. Sorry if this is a simple question but how do I change this so I can just fill in the form as is?

Comment: can you share some screenshots?

Comment: Is it actually a fillable form (with text boxes, etc.), or just  standard document?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the developer ribbon in Word 2007 (which you most likely have done). On that ribbon in the Controls box select the Legacy Tools dropbox, then select your form element, now you can set maximum length for a field. However, if I remember correctly you will have to lock / protect the document for form filling only to make this actually lock like you want it to.